# jQuery how to show hidden reply form?

Tags: jquery

I have my HTML set up in the following way:

```
<section class="comment-block">
    <div class="comment-title">
        ...
        <button class="reply_btn">Reply</button>
        ...                                                                             
    </div>

    <p class="comment">Test comment</p>

    <form method="POST" action="/org/post/{comment_id}" class="reply-form">
        <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">
        <textarea name="body" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
        <div class="button-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Post comment">
            <button type="button">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </form>                                 
</section>
```

Using jQuery, I want the Reply button (`reply_btn`) to change the CSS for the form (`reply-form`) from `display: none` to `display: block`.

There are multiple comments, so the jQuery click function attached to `reply_btn` must select the closest `reply-form` relative to itself.

I tried this (and a few other variations), but it doesn't work:

```
$('.comment-block').on('click', '.reply_btn', function () {
    $(this).children('.reply-form').css('display', 'block');
});
```

I then need the cancel button to change the display back to none.

The CSS for the form:

```
.comment-block .reply-form
{
   ...
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: You are looking for children of the button that was clicked!

Comment: What is hidden? The entire form?

Comment: @epascarello The entire form is hidden. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could similarly use `.parent()` twice in order to achieve the same results:

```
$(".reply_btn").click(function () {
  $(this).parent().parent().children('.reply-form').show();
});
```

I changed some of your HTML and added the close button functionality:

```
<section class="comment-block">
    <div class="comment-title">
        ...
        <button class="reply_btn">Reply</button>
        ...                                                                             
    </div>

    <p class="comment">Test comment</p>

    <form method="POST" action="/org/post/{comment_id}" class="reply-form">
        <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT"></input>
        <textarea name="body" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
        <div class="button-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Post Comment">Post comment</input>
            <input type="button" class="cancel_btn" value="Cancel"></input>
        </div>
    </form>                          
</section>
```

And this:

```
$(".cancel_btn").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().hide();
});
```

Working jsFiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jcoc611/K5tSv/).

Comment: using parent() is a bad idea, when the structure changes in the future...bam, your code is broken.

Comment: I don't think is that important to *expect* things to be different from what the OP has stated...but fair enough.

Answer (score 5):

change to this:

```
$(this).parent().siblings('.reply-form').css('display', 'block');
```

or

```
$(this).parent().siblings('.reply-form').show();
```

---

In your code you were trying to search that `.reply-form` as a child of button which is not the case.

Infact `.reply-form` is the sibling of the button's parent.

---

I think better is to use `.closest()` with `.find()`:

```
$(this).closest('.comment-block').find('.reply-form').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for siblings of the button with the class. That is not what you want.

Your code is:

```
$(this).children('.reply-form').css('display', 'block');
```

and it says:

```
$(this) <-- the button that was clicked
       .children('.reply-form')  <-- you are looking at children of the button
```

Now to fix the problem, you need to look at what was clicked on, traverse up to the container and look for the form. If you add a class to the reset button, you can do both things in one block.

```
$('.comment-block').on('click', '.reply_btn, .reset', function () {
    var show = $(this).is(".reply_btn");
    $(this).closest(".comment-block").find("form").toggle(show);
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XLrx5/)

Answer (score 0):

If the `form` element is hidden, the following code can be used to show by clicking the button:

```
$(function() {
    $('.comment-block').on('click', '.reply_btn', function () {
        $(this).closest( '.comment-block' ).find('.reply-form').show();
    });
});
```